# Angular 2: Load component dynamically with parameters @Input and @Output

Tags: angular

Currently I'm loading some of my components dynamically with this piece of code.

```
export class ComponentOutlet {

    constructor(
        private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private compiler: Compiler,
        private dataService: DataService
    ) { }

    private _createDynamicComponent() {

        // Some logic to decide which component should be loaded
        return MyComponent;
    }


    ngOnChanges() {

        this.compiler.compileComponentAsync(this._createDynamicComponent())
            .then(factory => {
                const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
                this.vcRef.clear();
                this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector);
            });
    }
```

The problem is that `MyComponent` has some `@Input` and `Output` bindings. Is it possible to set this bindings here? How can I achieve that?

Comment: With RC6+ there is now `.compileComponentAsync` .. check one option here http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310 *(also with bindings input)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler `compileComponentAsync` was removed in RC6. With RC6+ there is now `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`

Comment: @yurzui, correct.. that's what I am saying

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bindings to inputs and outputs can only be used to components that are statically added to another components template.

In your case you can do it imperatively like

```
 var cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector);
 cmpRef.instance.someInput = value;
 cmpRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Comment: Does ngOnChanges() of the instance gets triggered by Angular when adding the input? For me it doesn't. I have to call  cmpRef.instance.ngOnChanges() manually.

Comment: No, `ngOnChanges()` is called when `someProp` changes with `[someInput]="someProp"`. Without such a binding `ngOnChanges` won't be called. You can make `someInput` a setter and put the code there.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In this case we know inputs of the dynamically created component and give inputs as component needs. So what if we create different dynamic components according as a parameter and each dynamic component needs different inputs?  There should be a systematic way to pass input parameters from parent to child.

Comment: There is currently none. You need to come up with your own.